# How to maneuver the ship/mini-ship

Tags: geometry-dash

In Geometry Dash, the ship is the first gimmick differenciating the game from The Impossible Game.

The basic maneuvring is to hold the button/screen to fly up and to release to fly down, simple enough as introduced in Stereo Madness.

But then, in later levels, or worse, in user created levels, there are a lot of tight spaces where you have to maneuver your clumsy ship, and even worse, straight flights where I don't even know how you rythm your taps.

With any other gimmick like the wave or the UFO, you still can time your taps and holds, but the ship seems to be the bane of the up and down travels in this whole game. I am pretty sure that 80% of deaths in this game are in ship/mini-ship mode.

So, here is the question:
Anyone has any tip to maneuver the ship in those conditions?

- Straight fly
- Mini straight fly
- Faster speed in tight places
- Successive gravity switches with faster speed
- Successive gravity switches with faster speed in mini-ship mode

Edit: For your information, I mostly play on PC with a mouse, I don't have a controller and I'm not as fast as on the mouse when playing on a keyboard - I also started on mobile but my thumb play is even worse - But if you have advices for keyboard/controller/mobile players as well, I guess they are welcome

Comment: Practice makes perfect. There's little more advice than that I'm afraid.

Comment: are there practice user levels out there? I didn't really search for those yet, and the level editor scares me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I give specific advice, I would like to say one thing. Practice makes perfect. Search up levels like Ship Challenge and Straight Fly to make your own techniques by trial and error.

*Straight Fly* Here is what I do for straight fly. I click so that I do not run into the spikes above, but I don't fall to the spikes below, and when you fall back down to the same y-position as you were when you first clicked you click again for the same amount of time as when you first clicked in the straight fly. Repeat until the end of the straight fly.

*Mini Straight Fly* Same as above.

*Faster speed in tight places* If this is straight fly, then follow the techniques above. If not, then it is up to trial and error.

*Successive gravity switches with faster speed* If this is straight fly, then follow above technique until you reach first gravity switch. Then, follow above techniques with the exception of the first y-position you click at will be different (find new y-position where you will click will be up to trial and error). If not a straight fly, then it is up to trial and error.

*Successive gravity switches with faster speed in mini-ship mode* Same as above.

Comment: welcome to gaming.se, cool advices. Any specific online levels on your mind? I am already looking for those... how many practice mode successful attemps on one segment do you recommend before moving on to the next one?

Comment: Keep on playing until you beat in normal mode, but then if you cannot beat it, it is probably too hard at your level for now. Move on to another challenge level, and then come back to the original level. The number of attempts you normally should do on a challenge level should be around 100 attempts, if you can't beat it by then, move on and come back to the level.

Comment: roger, will do, already found a good practice level last night, it has speed, gravity, mini and even dual, it's like you choose your path

Comment: @gl_prout yes, I remember seeing a level like that, except with the wave. How has it gone so far?

Comment: I bought a controller, I could only finish the normal path with the normal ship so far; but I definitely am more confident in at least x3 speed flight segments

Comment: @gl_prout Cool! Glad this helped for you! You could also try making your own ship challenges and adjusting it to be harder and harder each time you beat it

Comment: I guess I don't really know yet how to use the editor to make that, but I'll definitely try it out